# need to re-arrange data of sql table

Tags: sql

I have following primary table.

```
ID  Email       TM  UR  EA1         TM1 UR1 TM2 UR2 TM3 UR3
1   abc@b.com   a1  b1  a@a.com     a2  b2  a3  b3  a4  b4
```

And need output as follows.

```
ID  Email       TM  UR
1   abc@b.com   a1  b1
1   a@a.com     a2  b2
1               a3  b3
1               a4  b4
```

**Edit**: I have already solved this by using `UNION`. I need optimize way to do that as I have many such columns for one record, and Union is not the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: a `union all` will most likely be faster - but apart from normalizing your _model_ I don't see a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Email, TM, UR
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, EA1 Email, TM1 TM, UR1 UR
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, '' Email, TM2 TM, UR2 UR
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, '' Email, TM3 TM, UR3 UR
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I have already tried that yesterday and it worked .. but i need optimize way if possible.